# Running a package code by command line without entering the folder of that package

Tags: bash, command-line, path, package, environment-variables

I have a package called CAMB (http://camb.info/readme.html). I can run the program by following `command: ./camb params.ini`

params.ini is a parameter file. How can I run it from my home directory by command?

I tried `export PATH=Path--to--my--package:$PATH`.
but what to do next? How can I get the output? when I am trying to type
`./camb params.ini` in my home directory, I am getting the error:

> ./camb: No such file or directory.

Please help me out in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the path in (the `./` in `./camb`), it looks in the current directory.

Just use `camb`, and the OS will search the PATH for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. But when I am writing camb params.ini. The error I am getting is STOP Error opening parameter file. But when I am going to that package path and running "./camb params.ini", it is working. I do not know why.

Comment: You need to give it the path to params.ini, e.g.: `camb /home/me/params.ini`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I have one last question. Suppose I am now writing a python programme using anaconda (spyder particularly). Now How can I run ./camb params.ini command and how I can generate output file from anaconda console ?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you.  Never used anaconda console.